# Facing problem when extracting tar.gz file in Google-Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tar

I am trying to extract `abc.tar.gz`

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open('abc.tar.gz')
tar.extractall()
```

**this raise error:**

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-a3ea34501364> in <module>()
      1 import tarfile
      2 tar = tarfile.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/abc.tar.gz')
----> 3 tar.extractall()

7 frames

/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py in read(self, size)
    480                 break
    481             if buf == b"":
--> 482                 raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
    483                                "end-of-stream marker was reached")
    484 

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem. This error would be consistent with `abc.targ.gz` being a malformed archive, but it's not possible to tell from the information provided in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```sh
!tar xvzf abc.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Current way is:

```
!tar -xf abc.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

weird thing, but -xf doesn't work anymore, unless you remove the hyphen. So the new command looks something like this -

```html
!tar xf filename.tar.gz
```